# Mallet basic usage. First steps

Tags: topic-modeling, mallet

I'm trying to use `Mallet` with literally no expirience in topic modeling and etc. My purpose is to get *N* topics of *M* documents that i have right now, classify every document with one or more topic (doc 1 = topic 1; doc 2 = topic 2 and possibly topic 3) and classify with this results new document in future. I tried to use `bigartm` for this first, but found nothing for classification in this program, only topic modeling. So Mallet, i created a corpus.txt file with following format:

`Doc.num. \t(tab) Label(actualy 1 everywhere) \t Text
1        1        some text of document to classify
2        1        another doc text
...`

For now I could get topics from this file after turning it to feature sequence format for mallet with

`bin/mallet import-file --input corpus.txt --output foo.mallet--keep-sequence`

and then get topics from it

`bin/mallet train-topics --input foo.mallet --output-state state.gz --output-topic-keys topic-keys.txt --output-doc-topics doc-topics.txt`

So general question now is what to use in mallet (train classifier?) to assign every existing document to a topic I found and to save this result to apply to future document that I want to classify with this topics.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is described as "inference" in Mallet topic models. Training a classifier is a separate package, aimed at directly learning relationships between words and a pre-existing set of classes.

Here are directions for using inference on new documents:

When you train a model with the `train-topics` command, add the `--inferencer-filename [FILENAME]` option. This option will create a topic inference tool based on the current, trained model and save it in a file.
If you already have a trained model, for example from `--output-state` or `--output-model` you can initialize from that state or model, run 0 iterations of sampling, and output an inferencer.

Once you've created the inferencer file, use the MALLET command `bin/mallet infer-topics --help` to get information on using topic inference.

Note that you must make sure that the new data is compatible with your training data. Otherwise word ID 425 might mean a completely different word. This will make all topics look equally probable. Use the option `--use-pipe-from [MALLET TRAINING FILE]` in the MALLET command `bin/mallet import-file` or `import-dir` to specify a training file.

Answer (score 1):

In the setting of your question, the human readable file `doc-topics.txt` contains the document-topic-matrix, i.e., the composition of every document in the corpus into topics. The topics are indicated by numbers, and their percentages are given. The format of the file is such that the topics are already ordered by their precedence, so the dominant topic comes first.

The file `topic-keys.txt` contains the first most topical words. You can use this file to guess some good lables for the topics. This labelling is mainly a manual task and it may involve going back to the documents and inspecting some of them to get at really good lables.

Comment: So, do you mean that I should write script for clasification myself for future purposes and there is no such opportunity in `Mallet` to train a classifier with this topics?

Comment: @Kirill: There is a possibility to apply a "pre-trained" topic model to new documents within Mallet; tho' I don't have the command line syntax at hands (`bin/mallet help` gives you a lot of usefull information, the mallet command `train-classifier` and `classify-file` are probably of interest to you.