# MALLET: Topic inference when training data was pruned

Tags: topic-modeling, mallet

I am trying to use MALLET to first train a topic model and then use the inferencer from that model on a set of new documents. 
From two other threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585370/mallet-basic-usage-first-steps) and on the [MALLET mailing list](https://mallet-dev.cs.umass.narkive.com/BqnPdTgn/topic-model-inference), I've gathered that is is important to ensure compatibility of training and test data by using the `--use-pipe-from [MALLET TRAINING FILE]` option. 
However, I prune the training data after importing it and fit the model on the pruned data.

```
/bin/mallet import-dir --input Train --output Train.mallet --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords
/bin/mallet prune --input $Train.mallet --output Train_pruned.mallet --prune-document-freq 10
/bin/mallet train-topics  --input Train_pruned.mallet --inferencer-filename inferencer --output-doc-topics doc-topics.txt
```

Now when trying to import the test data, the command

```
/bin/mallet import-dir --input Test --use-pipe-from Train_pruned.mallet
```

leads to an error saying "the alphabets don't match."

```
mallet Alphabets don't match: Instance: [null, null], InstanceList: [50024, 1]
```

The same command with `--use-pipe-from Train.mallet` instead of `Train_pruned.mallet` seems to run. I am unsure, though, if that actually leads to "compatible" data, as the inferred topic proportions for the test documents seem a bit weird to me.

Edit: 
the full commands are:

(1) Import the training data ✔

```
c:/mallet/bin/mallet import-dir --input “./data/Train” --output “./models/Train.mallet" --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --extra-stopwords “./my_stoplist.txt"
```

(2) Prune the training data ✔

```
c:/mallet/bin/mallet prune --input “./models/Train.mallet" --output “./models/Train_pruned.mallet" --prune-document-freq 10 --min-idf 0.1
```

(3) Train the model: ✔

```
c:/mallet/bin/mallet train-topics  --input “./models/Train_pruned.mallet" --optimize-interval 20 --num-topics 25 --output-topic-keys “./models/keys.txt” --output-doc-topics “./models/compostion.txt” --inferencer-filename “./models/inferencer.inferencer" --random-seed 1234
```

(4) Import the test data ✗

```
c:/mallet/bin/mallet import-dir --input “./data/Test” --output “./models/Test.mallet" --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --extra-stopwords “./my_stoplist.txt" --use-pipe-from “./models/Train_pruned.mallet"
```

Where (4) leads to the following error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Alphabets don't match: Instance: [null, null], InstanceList: [50024,
>   1]
>
> ```
>     at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.add(InstanceList.java:335)
>     at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.addThruPipe(InstanceList.java:267)
>     at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors.main(Text2Vectors.java:322)
> ```

Comment: Pruning shouldn't make any difference. What command specifically is causing the Alphabets don't match error? (It can't be the import, since there's nothing to match to)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, David! It actually IS the import command, though. At least when using the ```-use-pipe-from``` option with the pruned data. Or am I making a mistake elsewhere?